# Non-constant overdispersion (overdispersion parameter depending on covariate) in negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, overdispersion, mgcv

In a negative binomial regression (daily number of cases of a disease over time), after controlling for several factors and experimenting with several functional forms, my results still don't look good, but I think I have found the reason. Here are the residuals plotted versus time stratified according to day-of-week:

[image]

I'm not sure, but my impression is that what we see here is that the overdispersion depends on the day of week. (And is also non-constant over time, but that's the smaller problem, I could restrict the analysis to >2006.)

The first question is whether I am correct, the second is simply: what to do...?

The regression is actually a GAM model, realized with the `mgcv` package. More specifically, the final model is

```
fit <- gam( N ~  DOW + Swap + NWD + s( PROCDATEnum, by = DOW ) +
s( DOY, bs = "ad", xt = list( bs = "cc" ) ), offset = log( Population ),
data = TimeStratified2, family = nb( link = log ) )
```

where `TimeStratified2` contains the daily number of cases (`N`) with the appropriate at-risk background population (`Population`), and the predictors are different characteristics of the day. (`DOW`: day-of-week, `Swap`: swapped working/non-working day, `NWD`: non-working day due to national holiday, `DOY`: day-of-year (not as number, but as fraction from 0 to 1 to account for leap years) and `PROCDATEnum`: date numerically.)

Comment: Can you show the model call or explain the structure of the model? (Plus what models you tried.)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Sure! I edited the post accordingly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you have checked that `k` is sufficient for the `by = DOW` term?

Comment: Anyway, you can model theta in the *brms* package, which uses mgcv's smooths, but you can't use an adaptive spline in this mixed-model representation.

Comment: @GavinSimpson "And you have checked that k is sufficient for the by = DOW term?" Yes-yes, I have, I omitted it here just for simplicity. "Anyway, you can model theta in the brms package, which uses mgcv's smooths, but you can't use an adaptive spline in this mixed-model representation." What a pity, unfortunately I definitely need adaptiveness here... I'll nevertheless check that package, thanks for the suggestion!